# Copy only text from next list with selected class

Tags: jquery

I have a list which works as a selectbox, so by clicking on the selected item a list shows up and you can select another item.

This works fine but when I try to make two or more lists, the name of the selected copies to all selected names (the `.cloned` span) where it should only be the one from the next one, in the jsfiddle example instead of "Item 1.1Item 2.2" the first span with class cloned should just display "Item 1.1" and the one below displaying "Item1.1Item2.2" should be "Item2.2" as it is the title/selected item in the second list and so on..

I found the problem lies in the following code:

```
$(".cloned").text($(".selected").text());
```

I've tried the following but not working:

```
$(".cloned").text($(".options").closest(".selected").text());
```

How can I only display the `.selected` class from the list in the `.clone` span of the list right under it?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9BR9h/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` selects the closest `parent` of the selected element, not the closest element, you can use `parent` and `prev` methods.

```
$('.options li').click(function () {
    $(this)
          .addClass('selected')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('selected')
          .parent()
          .hide()
          .prev('.cloned')
          .text(this.textContent || this.innerText);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B2nZH/

On the page load you can use the `text`'s function:

```
$(".cloned").text(function(){
     return $(this).next().find(".selected").text()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zKfX2/

Comment: `if (answer == (function (undefined) { return undefined; })()) $('vote-up-off').click();`

Comment: Thanks undefined, works nice and finally rid of the duplicate when clicking. But on default when the page loads I still have the same problem.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! So what I had in mind in the likes of ($(".cloned").text($(".selected").text());) would never work without a function then?

Comment: @user1901096 You are welcome, no, that way you have your initial result.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thanks once again, upvoted and accepted answer.